# Terminal broken in Intellij 13 when run idea64.exe

Tags: intellij-idea, cygwin, intellij-13

I'm using Intellij 13.1.3 on a 64bit machine. When I run idea.exe the cygwin terminal within Intellij works fine but if I run idea64.exe, terminal opens up but no prompt. Ideas please?

Comment: What happens to Cygwin if you run it _first_ and then launch IntelliJ 14?  Does it freeze or does it keep running?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry I meant the Cygwin terminal within Intellij. And I meant idea64.exe.  Updated the question

Comment: You can try to take a thread dump of IntelliJ at the moment you try launching Cygwin.  You can read about this [here](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-260).

Comment: In response to your question about the downvote, it might be because the question is very brief. There is an assumption on Stack Overflow - usually well-founded unfortunately - that brief posts are unresearched. I am sure it is not the case here, but if you can add more detail even for seemingly trivial problems, that does help.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP):*

I solved the problem by starting idea.bat instead of starting idea64.exe directly.